# Reference to undeclared resource in Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I am trying to run a test server on aws using terraform. When i run  `terraform apply` it throws an error saying **Reference to undeclared resource**. Below is my test server file inside terraform.

test-server.tf

```
module "test-server" {
  source = "./node-server"
  ami-id = "Here ive given my ami_id"
  key-pair = aws_key_pair.microservices-demo-key.key_name
  name = "Test Server"
}
```

Below is my key pair file code.

**key-pairs**

```
resource "aws_key_pair" "microservcies-demo-key" {
  key_name = "microservices-demo-key"
  public_key = file("./microservices_demo.pem")
}
```

Error detail thrown by terraform:

**Error: Reference to undeclared resource**

**on test-server.tf line 4, in module "test-server":**

**4:   key-pair = aws_key_pair.microservices-demo-key.key_name**

**A managed resource "aws_key_pair" "microservices-demo-key" has not been declared in the root module.**

Although ive declard the variables. Its still throwing the error.
This is the image of the directory.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you first create the key pair and after the test server? You need the first to be created before the second can be created. Declare the Aws key pair outside the module.

Comment: Is `key-pairs` in a file with a `.tf` extension? Is that file in the same folder as the `test-server.tf` file?

Comment: @markB yes, ```key-pairs``` has .tf extension. Yes, the file is in same folder with server.tf

Comment: @Lucasz i am going to edit the question and upload a picture of my directory for clarity. Kindly, look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo here:

```
resource "aws_key_pair" "microservcies-demo-key" {
```

Fix this name to be `microservices-demo-key` so that it matches the name you reference in `test-server.tf`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and that how I landed here but unfortunately i didnt get any response. So I tried resolving this problem on my own and instead accessing the key with Argument I tried to access this with value and I would suggest you the same.
You can try `key_name = "microservices-demo-key"` rather `key-pair = aws_key_pair.microservices-demo-key.key_name`